# Which Query language to use when testing ORM performance?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, nhibernate, orm, comparison

I want to compare the performance of the most popular .NET ORMs (EF, NHibernate, Telerik Data Access, XPO, LLBGenPro), to do that, I will run many tests and measure the average execution time.

I have an abstract class that defines the test methods that will be overridden and implemented for each ORM, the problem/confusion is : for each ORM there are many ways of querying (NHibernate  for instance has API Criteria, Query Over, HQL, Native Sql), so what's the most convenient way to do an unbiased comparison, I mean which query language should I choose for each ORM and based on what I will choose it (popularity, ease of use..)?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some benchmark of ORM tools for .Net on the web.

I would suggest you to use the same query provider to each item. For sample, the `LINQ` is the default on the .Net, so, many ORM tools provide support for `LINQ`.

With this, you could have a single method which takes and `IQueryable<T>` as a parameter and test it for each item of your benchmark.

Comment: Thanks Felipe! I find it reasonable to test all the ORMs against LINQ, can you please point me to some good benchmarks for ORM testing or at least tell me what should I consider while choosing a benchmark?